# How to create a select drop-down using data from an array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, drop-down-menu, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects that I'd like to use to populate a Select option dropdown, but these elements do not already exist and must be created from scratch.

I have working code using the `createElement` method, but I can't use that method nor can I use `options.add(new Option())`. How else can I create the select and option elements in the JavaScript?

```js
  var optionsList = [
     {
     label: "Option 1",
     value: "option-1"
     },
    
     {
     label: "Option 2",
     value: "option-2"
     },
     {
     label: "Option 3",
     value: "option-3"
     }
    ];
    
    if (optionsList.length == 0) {
     console.log("No data");
    } else {
     var selectTag = document.createElement("SELECT");
     document.body.appendChild(selectTag);
    
     for (var i = 0; i < optionsList.length; i++) {
      var option = optionsList[i];
      selectTag.options.add(new Option(option.label, option.value));
     }
    }
```

Comment: What "I can't use that" means?

Comment: Sorry, I meant I cannot use that method to create the select element, nor can I use options.add(new Option()

Answer (score 2):

You can just make a string with template literals (easier and more concise than concatenation) and append that to the select element:

```
optionsList.forEach(e => selectTag.innerHTML += `<option value=${e.value}>${e.text}</option>`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saying

```
selectTag.options.add(new Option(...))
```

Simply create a new 'option' element and then add it to the select tag like this

```
optionsList.forEach(function(item, index, array) {

   var opt = document.createElement("option");
   opt.text = item.label;
   opt.value = item.value;

   selectTag.add(opt);
});
```

You can look at this link https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp for more info.

and a working example here https://jsfiddle.net/L5342j0y/

Comment: But is it possible to create the elements without using the createElement() method?

Answer (score 0):

The following HTML and JavaScript shows how to add a Select and Options using data from an array of objects containing option labels and their values:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="app()">
    <p>Select your choice:</p>
    <div id="div-id">
       <!-- The select with data gets added here -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*app.js*:

```
function app() {

    var optionsList = [
        {
        label: "Option 1",
        value: "option-1"
        },
        {
        label: "Option 2",
        value: "option-2"
        },
        {
        label: "Option 3",
        value: "option-3"
        }
    ];

    var selectTag = document.createElement("select");

    for (let optObj of optionsList) {
        let optEle = document.createElement("option");
        optEle.text = optObj.label;
        optEle.value = optObj.value;
        selectTag.add(optEle);
    }

    var div = document.getElementById("div-id");
    div.appendChild(selectTag);
};
```